# Why my prisma.update call is not working for prisma.$transaction?

Tags: node.js, prisma

I'm using Prisma 4.13 in a nodejs application and trying to run the following transaction in a service method.

```
const {createPurchase, updatePurchase} = require('../dao/PurchaseDao.ts')
const {insertPurchaseItems, deletePurchaseItemsByPurchaseId} = require('../dao/PurchaseItemDao.ts')

const savePurchase = async (purchase) => {

      await prisma.$transaction([
        deletePurchaseItemsByPurchaseId(purchase.purchaseId),
        insertPurchaseItems(purchase.purchaseItems),
        updatePurchase(purchase)
      ])
  }
}
```

But get the following warning (which turns out to be an error during runtime):

```
Argument type [runtime.Types.Public.PrismaPromise<BatchPayload>, runtime.Types.Public.PrismaPromise<BatchPayload>, Promise<any>] is not assignable to parameter type [...Prisma.PrismaPromise<any>[]]
```

Apparently the last method is not returning a `PrismaPromise` but rather a regular `Promise`

These are the implementation of the dao methods:

```
const deletePurchaseItemsByPurchaseId = async (purchaseId) => {
  return prisma.purchaseItem.deleteMany({
    where: {
      purchaseId: purchaseId
    }
  })
}
```

```
const insertPurchaseItems = async (purchaseItems) => {
  return prisma.purchaseItem.createMany({data: purchaseItems})
}
```

```
const updatePurchase = async (purchase) => {
  return prisma.purchase.update({
    where: {
      purchaseId: purchase.purchaseId
    },
    data: {
      globalDiscount: purchase.globalDiscount,
      Storage: {
        connect: {storageId: purchase.storageId}
      },
      Supplier: {
        connect: {supplierId: purchase.supplierId}
      },
      orgId: purchase.orgId
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you try changing update with updateMany and check if that resolves the error?